# How to minify a Flutter app with Proguard?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, proguard, minify

I already made a Flutter app. The release apk is about 14MB. I searched methods to minify this and found this ons: https://flutter.io/android-release/#enabling-proguard

But my question is, **how can I get to know all my used additional libraries** for step 1? Are there any commands to know them or is it just all the dependencies that I added to the `pubspec.yaml` ?

**How** do I need **to implement** them in this file `/android/app/proguard-rules.pro`?

Comment: I doubt pro guard will do much. Dart compile use tree shaking already. So unless you code directly in Java (which is unlikely), the win is minimal. Maybe that size comes from your assets.

Comment: That's possible, but at least I could give it a try if I know what rules I need to add to the proguard-rules.pro file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter apps are too big in size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064969/flutter-apps-are-too-big-in-size)

Comment: https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-and-android-obfuscation-8768ac544421

Comment: Did you find the answer for your question ?  If yes, please share the answer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First, we will enable shrinking and obfuscation in the build file. Find `build.gradle` file which sits inside `/android/app/` folder and add lines in bold

```
android {

    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug     

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 

        }
    }
}
```

Next we will create a configuration which will preserve entire Flutter wrapper code. Create `/android/app/proguard-rules.pro` file and insert inside:

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```

Note: Use `signingConfigs.release` instead `signingConfigs.debug` to build a apk or appbundle

Comment: don't use this line for release apk-->           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug     
use -->             signingConfig signingConfigs.release

Comment: Any update on proguard for flutter wrapper code?
Where do I find these default proguard lines?

Answer (score 32):

I will leave this answer here as an addition for any poor soul that has to deal with this issue and encounters this thread.

As of December 2021 with the latest Android Sdk, Studio and Flutter versions, if you try to do`useProguard true` it will not work because it's obsolete.
Sadly, Gradle will not tell you this, instead, you will get an error like this:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_7cqkbrda1q788z3b02yxbvrx9.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_7cqkbrda1q788z3b02yxbvrx9$_run_closure2) values: [build_7cqkbrda1q788z3b02yxbvrx9$_run_closure2@41108b15]
```

Which as you can see it is complete gibberish and not useful. The secret is to just not use `useProguard` at all. By default Flutter is setup to use R8 which handles minification now on Android.

Here is a so post about this for reference: [Gradle : DSL element 'useProguard' is obsolete and will be removed soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635963/gradle-dsl-element-useproguard-is-obsolete-and-will-be-removed-soon)

Comment: Been struggling on this for an hour now.

Comment: You are n live safer. I still have one question: When I publish my app to play store it sill warns me that proguard is missing. Is this normal?

Answer (score 6):

### Latest Solution

At first you should use `shrinkResources true` instead of `useProguard true` in `android/app/build.gradle`.

In second instead of using `proguard-android.txt` you should use `proguard-android-optimize.txt`.

[Update] Attention: If you don't want to optimize, use the `proguard-android.txt` configuration file instead of this one, which
turns off the optimization flags. Adding optimization introduces
certain risks, since for example not all optimizations performed by
ProGuard works on all versions of Dalvik. To check how to turn off various optimization you need to read more at [official Google Proguard reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android-optimize.txt).

```
buildTypes {
              
    release {
         signingConfig signingConfigs.release

         minifyEnabled true
         shrinkResources true
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
}
```

Following is newer version of proguard configuration rules to prevent logging and other retrofit protection:

```
# Flutter
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.** { *; }

# Retrofit
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

# OkHTTP
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-keep class okhttp3.**{ *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.**{ *; }

# Other
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable

# Logging 
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** wtf(...);
}

-assumenosideeffects class io.flutter.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}

-assumenosideeffects class java.util.logging.Level {
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}

-assumenosideeffects class java.util.logging.Logger {
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}

# Removes third parties logging
-assumenosideeffects class org.slf4j.Logger {
    public *** trace(...);
    public *** debug(...);
    public *** info(...);
    public *** warn(...);
    public *** error(...);
}
```

To check it, install `jadx` and open `your_app.apk` and search inside of that about `log`. You should have comparison between non-proguard .apk and proguard configured .apk log search result.

### Without Proguard rules

[image: Before proguard configuration rules]

### With Proguard rules

[image: After config rules]

[Read more in official Android documentations](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/risks/log-info-disclosure#strip_logs_to_logcat_from_production_builds_by_using_r8).

[Read more](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#enable) about Android code shrink.

Comment: Careful with `proguard-android-optimize.txt`, as it will turn on some potentially dangerous optimizations. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902356/proguard-android-optimize-txt-vs-proguard-android-txt-in-android-build-gradle

Comment: @DarkNeuron Based on [official Android shrink and obfuscate](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#full-mode), R8 ignores any ProGuard rules that attempt to modify default optimizations, such as `-optimizations` and `-optimizationpasses` flags. If you think R8 is difference with this hypothesis, I will edit and update my answer. Thanks

Comment: Well there's a difference depending on the file name you use, see: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android-optimize.txt

Answer (score 2):

If you are using firebase, see [Flutter build crashes using ProGuard with Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912130/flutter-build-crashes-using-proguard-with-firebase-auth)

Next, you need to consider the dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` You can immediately ignore any pure Dart packages - you are just looking for plugins. Of these plugins, you are just interested in ones that make use of existing libraries. You will likely have added these to gradle. Those are the ones you need to protect from name shortening.

The simplest approach may just be to try it and see what package names pop up in the `NoClassDefFoundError` and keep iteratively adding them.

As Remi says, your gain will be minimal, so is it really worth the hassle. You should see some improvements in APK sizes over the coming releases.

Answer (score 0):

By default flutter enable it on command flutter build at least on version 3.19.x

[References](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiXwb36-_2EAxWi6KACHYHkDpgQFnoECBUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.flutter.dev%2Fdeployment%2Fandroid&usg=AOvVaw2nyVN8ZyRh667M2gjIvQO7&opi=89978449)