# After setting shrinkResources and minifyEnabled values true getting crash in android release build in SOA page http://flutter_inappwebview.in

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient: void com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient.access$501(com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient, android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.SslErrorHandler, a.b) failed to verify: void com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient.access$501(com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient, android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.SslErrorHandler, a.b): [0x0] register v3 has type Reference: a.b but expected Reference: android.net.http.SslError
void com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient.access$601(com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient, android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.SslErrorHandler, a.b) failed to verify: void com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient.access$601(com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient, android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.SslErrorHandler, a.b): [0x0] register v3 has type Reference: a.b but expected Reference: android.net.http.SslError
void com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient.onReceivedClientCertRequest(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.ClientCertRequest) failed to verify: void com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient.onReceivedClientCertRequest(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.ClientCertRequest): [0x28] register v6 has type Reference: android.net.http.SslCertificate but expected Reference: a.a
void com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) failed to verify: void com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebViewClient.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.

App is getting crashed after enabling these flags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59202013/5894542